# how can I add or remove rows of my matrix in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a matrix by using a div element which includes some p-tags and each p-tag has some inputs. Now, I want to edit this matrix and add or remove some columns or rows. I surfed the net and found the remove() command in Jquery. but when I continuously add and remove some rows, I face with some things. do you have any idea?

```
//instruction of my matrix:
var d = document.createElement("div")
dmatid = 'a'
d.setAttribute('id', dmatid)
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var p = document.createElement("p")
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    var pp = document.createElement("input")
    pp.type = "number"
    pp.value = eval(mat.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].value)
    p.appendChild(pp)
  }
  d.appendChild(p)
}
// the code to remove some rows of the matrix:
if (newrow < oldrow) {
  for (var i = newrow; i < oldrow; i++) {
    $("#" + dmatid + " p").last().remove()
  }
}

// the code to add some rows to the matrix:
else if (newrow > oldrow) {
  for (var i = oldrow; i < newrow; i++) {
    var drow = document.createElement("div")

    for (j = 0; j < mats[d].colnum; j++) {
      var p = document.createElement("input")

      drow.appendChild(p)
    }
    document.getElementById(dmatid).appendChild(drow)
  } ** strong text **
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as a replacement way to facing this problem, i think you can set an attribute to any cell of your matrix as data-row and another as data-col. that the value of each one is the number of row and col of matrix.

so the cell element will be like(as example) :

```
<input data-row="4" data-cel="3" type="number"/>
```

So, any time you want delete a row, toy can delete all nodes with same "data-row" attribute.
for example:

```
$("[data-row=4]").remove();
```

that $("[data-row=4]") gets all element that the attribute "data-row" in them have value 4 and remove them.

sorry about alternative way, the codes you have posted was not pretty clear for me.